# What is the role of length scale bound in sklearn Radial Basis Function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, rbf-kernel, rbf-network

The radial basis function provided by SkLearn ([reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF.html)) has two parameters: length scale and length scale bounds. I understand that the length scale controls the importance of the coordinates of the input. However, it is realy not clear for me the role of the length scale bounds.

1. Can anyone explain me what is its role?
2. Is there any "correct" way to choose it?